# Jupyter notebook reload and import again

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook. 
after I done with some work I turn off the computer
and after reopen Jupyter.The previous code which I typed includes import seemed not working. Therefore, I have to retype everything again.
any solutions on this problem?

Comment: Did you try re-running the cells that contained the import statements?